# Query Object Titles to Labels

Tags: ios, arrays, label, parse-platform

I have a Parse query that runs to gather the 10 closest Arcades in your area, and I am trying to have them display those object titles in 10 separate labels. I have the following code which gathers the 10 closest and logs them, and I am trying to start by displaying the objectId in the labels but cannot figure out how to display them all and not just 1. Any suggestions?

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Arcade"];
CLLocation *currentLocation = locationManager.location;
PFGeoPoint *userLocation =
[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                       longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
query.limit = 10;
[query whereKey:kPAWParseLocationKey nearGeoPoint:userLocation withinMiles:kPAWWallPostMaximumSearchDistance];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // The find succeeded.
        NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
        // Do something with the found objects
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            NSString *EventTitle = object.objectId;
            EventTitle1.text = EventTitle;
            for (UIImageView *imageView in self.imageViews) {
                __block UIImage *MyPicture = [[UIImage alloc]init];
                PFFile *imageFile = [object objectForKey:@"test"];
                [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error){
                    if (!error) {
                        MyPicture = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                        imageView.image = MyPicture;
                    }
                }];
            }
            for (UILabel *EventLabel in self.EventTitles){
                EventLabel.text = object.objectId;
            }
        }
```

UPDATE: I have created two collection outlets, however when they display they only display the final object queried, not all 10 of them? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why labels? Why not a table view?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `EventTitle1.text = EventTitle;`, because you explicitly reference the label. What you should be doing is updating the labels in sequence. This could be done by having the labels in an array (perhaps an `IBOutletCollection`) and using the iteration index. Or you could tag all of the labels and then look them up (again, using the iteration index).

But, your intended solution isn't simple and doesn't scale. It would be better to use a table view (Parse SDK even gives you an easy way to populate a table view from a query).